# QGIS labels with multiple rule based icon

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, rule-based

I'm learning QGIS. I have drilling locations showing on a map with a specific SVG icon (D1 and D2). I also have my labels showing the name of the soil sample taken in each drilling and the contaminants analysis results (like shown in the attached table). One or more samples results can be displayed for one drilling (ex. D2-S1 and D2-S2). I would like to insert a symbol (like the ones in the table) showing the result for each contaminant at the end (or at the beginning) of the line of the label where the result is displayed.

[image]
[image]

Type of display needed:

[image]

I have tried to add layers for each contaminant with rule based symbols but it doesn't allow me to move the labels freely, more so when 2 or more samples are related to one drilling.

Is there a way to do such a thing in QGIS ?

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it is to add background symbol to your label, as shape choose 'Marker Symbol' (at this stage let the default circle)  for Size type set 'Fixed'. Adjust the symbol size and the X offset (do not adjust the Y here) to place the symbol after your text.

Then go to the Marker Symbol setting to further adjust it :

- Duplicate your Marker two time to get three symbol
- Adjust the y offset of each symbol to align them to the line of text
- Use data defined override to set the symbol shape and color

For the fill color of the first line symbol set :

```
CASE
    WHEN  "Contamin1"  =  '<A'  THEN '#32CD32'
    WHEN "Contamin1"  =  'A-B'  THEN '#FFFF00'
    When  "Contamin1" =  'B-C'  Then '#FF0000'
END
```

As expression (for the second and third symbol change the field from "Contamin1" to "Contamin2" and "Contamin3" respectively)

For the shape of the first line symbol set :

```
CASE
    WHEN  "Contamin1"  =  '<A'  THEN 'Circle'
    WHEN "Contamin1"  =  'A-B'  THEN 'Triangle'
    When  "Contamin1" =  'B-C'  Then 'Square'
END
```

As expression (for the second and third symbol change the field from "Contamin1" to "Contamin2" and "Contamin3" respectively)

[image]

[image]

This way your labels and symbol stay one object and you should be able to move them easily

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you, it works very well.

Answer (score 3):

Another route is to use virtual fields and unicode symbols.
This might or not be useful, since it produces monochrome labels, but it is probably quite straightforward.

From the table view of the sampling vector layer:

[image]

you should obtain:

[image]

Selecting the virtual field as the label to be displayed:

[image]

Expression used for the Virtual Field:

```
Concat(
CASE
    WHEN  "Contamin1"  =  '<A'   THEN concat('',' Contaminant 1:',"Contamin1")
    WHEN  "Contamin1"  =  'A'    THEN concat('◹',' Contaminant 1:',"Contamin1")
    WHEN  "Contamin1"  =  'B'    THEN concat('',' Contaminant 1:',"Contamin1")
    WHEN  "Contamin1"  =  'C'    THEN concat('',' Contaminant 1:',"Contamin1")
    WHEN  "Contamin1"  =  'A-B'  THEN concat('',' Contaminant 1:',"Contamin1")
END
,
'\n',
CASE
    WHEN  "Contamin2"  =  '<A'   THEN concat('',' Contaminant 2:',"Contamin2")
    WHEN  "Contamin2"  =  'A'    THEN concat('◹',' Contaminant 2:',"Contamin2")
    WHEN  "Contamin2"  =  'B'    THEN concat('',' Contaminant 2:',"Contamin2")
    WHEN  "Contamin2"  =  'C'    THEN concat('',' Contaminant 2:',"Contamin2")
    WHEN  "Contamin2"  =  'A-B'  THEN concat('',' Contaminant 2:',"Contamin2")
END
,
'\n',
CASE
    WHEN  "Contamin3"  =  '<A'   THEN concat('',' Contaminant 3:',"Contamin3")
    WHEN  "Contamin3"  =  'A'    THEN concat('◹',' Contaminant 3:',"Contamin3")
    WHEN  "Contamin3"  =  'B'    THEN concat('',' Contaminant 3:',"Contamin3")
    WHEN  "Contamin3"  =  'C'    THEN concat('',' Contaminant 3:',"Contamin3")
    WHEN  "Contamin3"  =  'A-B'  THEN concat('',' Contaminant 3:',"Contamin3")
END
)
```

Comment: You don't need to create virtual field, just input your expression as label value, also HTML color formating (available since 3.14, see this for use https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html#text-tab) should let you set the symbol color as well

Answer (score 3):

Building on [@J.R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/105900/j-r) suggestion:

[image]

Please note that:

1. you need to enable thee `Allow HTML formatting`
2. you need to insert a '@' symbol in the  `Wrap on character` field

[image]

```
concat (
CASE
    WHEN  "Contamin1"  =  '<A'   THEN concat('<span style="color:green"></span>',' Contaminant 1:&lt;A')
    WHEN  "Contamin1"  =  'RESC' THEN concat('<span style="color:blue">◹</span>',' Contaminant 1:',Contamin1)
    WHEN  "Contamin1"  =  'B-C'  THEN concat('<span style="color:red"></span>',' Contaminant 1:',Contamin1)
    WHEN  "Contamin1"  =  'A-B'  THEN concat('<span style="color:#ECDE1C"></span>',' Contaminant 1:',Contamin1)
    ELSE  ' '
END,
'@',
CASE
    WHEN  "Contamin2"  =  '<A'   THEN concat('<span style="color:green"></span>',' Contaminant 2:&lt;A')
    WHEN  "Contamin2"  =  'RESC' THEN concat('<span style="color:blue">◹</span>',' Contaminant 2:',Contamin2)
    WHEN  "Contamin2"  =  'B-C'  THEN concat('<span style="color:red"></span>',' Contaminant 2:',Contamin2)
    WHEN  "Contamin2"  =  'A-B'  THEN concat('<span style="color:#ECDE1C"></span>',' Contaminant 2:',Contamin2)
    ELSE  ' '
END,
'@',
CASE
    WHEN  "Contamin3"  =  '<A'   THEN concat('<span style="color:green"></span>',' Contaminant 3:&lt;A')
    WHEN  "Contamin3"  =  'RESC' THEN concat('<span style="color:blue">◹</span>','  Contaminant 3:',Contamin3)
    WHEN  "Contamin3"  =  'B-C'  THEN concat('<span style="color:red"></span>','  Contaminant 3:',Contamin3)
    WHEN  "Contamin3"  =  'A-B'  THEN concat('<span style="color:#ECDE1C"></span>',' Contaminant 3:',Contamin3)
    ELSE  ' '
END
)
```

Comment: To escape the "<" see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-in-html

Comment: Thanks @J.R: HTML-style escaping actually made the trick! :)